# Unable to pass an object of a class from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-activity, serializable

Code for passing the Object in the passing class

```
final ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo = getSongsFromDirectory(f);
public void onItemClick(AdapterView a, View v, int position, long id) {


               Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlaying.class);
               intent.putExtra("Data1",songinfo);

               intent.putExtra("Data2",position);
               startActivity(intent);

                     }
             });
```

code in the retrieving class

```
Intent i = getIntent();


        ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo2 = (ArrayList<SongDetails>)i.getSerializableExtra("Data1"); 
        position=i.getIntExtra("Data2", 1);
```

i have implemented Serializable in both the classes as well as in the class SongDetails class(of which i am passing the object of)

Comment: What doesn't work? What are the errors? What happens?

Comment: When i want to open the new activity ..the activity where i am passing my objects..the app crashes

Comment: you can pass an arraylist as per iandownie's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18149853/383414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using parcels.....

using parcels is a better and faster way then using serializable

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass an object you can use the `Parcelable` [interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).  [Bundles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)
can hold any parcelable, and `Intent`s can hold any `Bundle` with them as they cross boundaries between different `Activity`s and processes.

Comment: yeah thanx....i am trying to implement that right now but can you find any bugs in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Use Bundles, e.g.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Mapper.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("A_STRING", aString);
myIntent.putExtras(b);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

Then

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
aString = b.getString("A_STRING");
```

But adapt for your purposes.

Addition: Presumably you would need to use something like

```
b.putParcelableArrayList(String key, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)
```

and

```
b.getParcelableArrayList(String key)
```

Comment: My object is not of string type

Comment: I'm trying to help you write your own code, and I ended the answer with "But adapt for your purposes." Please have a try using the 'example' above. You aren't using `Bundles` according to the minimal code you use in the question, so I suggest you add that into your code?

Comment: yeah i know that but what should i put here??

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("A_STRING", aString);

instead of "b.putString" what should i write??